Not able to fetch record using SOQL in adf copy or lookup activity
I'm trying to fetch the record from salesforce using soql query inside a copy activity, but it seems like adf is not able to parse the query because it's giving me this error
SOQL query: Select Id from Account
Error:
The value of the property '' is invalid: 'SOQLQuery, objectApiName, reportId cannot be null or whitespace'. SOQLQuery, objectApiName, reportId cannot be null or whitespace
I'm passing a valid soql query, however this is what is happening when I'm previewing the dataset however when I run the pipeline it is successful but it gives all the fields so it makes me think whether it's ignoring the SOQL query or is my user not able to run SOQL query. The user that I'm using is API only user.


The value of the property '' is invalid: 'SOQLQuery, objectApiName, reportId cannot be null or whitespace'

The error in the preview might be due to the loading. Try to publish the pipeline and then preview to get it sorted. As its working for you during the debug run, it is the correct query because Debug run will take the data from the source as there might be loading issue during the preview part.
Additionally, you can also try like below to achieve your result.
Select the Table name in the source and import the schema in the mapping.

In the mapping, you can remove the columns which you don't want in the target table.

You can also change the data types as well by changing the pipeline JSON of the mapping.
